# how to call onclick event in jquery once page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using following code for a particular page on which i want the tabs(course descriptions and other version) to be clicked and show contents during the page load but it is not working...here is the code with the link of the page:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/

```
window.onload=function() {
  init();
  function init() {
    var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
    var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
    tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
    contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
    var i = 0;
    for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
      tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
      tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
      if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

But i am little bit confused in syntax part.  the tabs are only able to show contents when the entire page loads. but i need to show the content when user clicks on tabs during please loading.

Comment: Change the event from onload to anything else you want, window.onload will load the function once when the webpage is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can do this as given below

```
$("document").ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );

  $("id").trigger('click');
},10);
});
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: hey Neeraj, i used this but was not able to get the desired result. what should i put at the place of "ul.galleria". can you check it from the code i provided and help me.

Comment: Hey Ranjan,I have updated the code,you can pass your first tab id like `$("id").trigger('click');` this and do your work.